# Why does Chrome display different validation messages depending on the browser startup mode?

Tags: google-chrome, headless

I have index.html file:

```html
<input required>
<script>
  document.write( document.querySelector('input').validationMessage )
</script>
```

When I open this file in Chrome, in normal mode (with UI interface rendering), the script outputs the message: `Please fill in this field`.
↓
[image: headed mode]

---

But, when I open this file in headless mode (chrome --headless index.html), the script outputs the message: `Please fill out this field`. (`in` changed to `out`).
↓
[image]

Why does the message text change depending on the browser open (headed/headless) mode?

Chrome: Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (x86_64)
macOS: 11.6 (20G165)